# sigc++ with lambda giving error: void value not ignored as it ought to be

Tags: c++, c++11, libsigc++

I have a `libsigc++` signal which is connected to a c++11 lambda.

```
sigc::signal<void, std::string> foo;

foo.connect([](string s) { cout << s << endl; });

foo.emit(string("Hello"));
```

I want to change the signal's return type from `void` to non-void

```
sigc::signal<int, std::string> foo;

foo.connect([](string s) { return s.size(); });

cout << foo.emit(string("Hello")) << endl;
```

This gives an error:

> void value not ignored as it ought to be

Is this usage pattern possible with lambdas?

Answer (score 2):

See the mention of SIGC_FUNCTORS_DEDUCE_RESULT_TYPE_WITH_DECLTYPE here: https://developer.gnome.org/libsigc++/stable/group__slot.html#details

You should just need to put this near the top of your source file:

```
namespace sigc {
  SIGC_FUNCTORS_DEDUCE_RESULT_TYPE_WITH_DECLTYPE
}
```

Hopefully we'll make this unnecessary with future C++11-only versions of libsigc++.

You'll probably want to use sigc::track_obj() too: https://developer.gnome.org/libsigc++/unstable/group__track__obj.html#details

Comment: Nice! Looking forward to trying this out. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the compilation error for me, when trying to connect a signal to a C++ lambda, without having to use the funky functor class shown above. I'm on Debian 8.2 so have libsigc 2.4 - another reason to bite the bullet and migrate to testing...

Answer (score 1):

Loong Jin provides a solution in [this newsgroup posting](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/libsigc-list/2012-January/msg00000.html).

> Just put [this code] in a header somewhere and #include it when you want to use
>   lambdas. It also allows you to throw std::function, boost::function, or any
>   other object with an appropriate operator() at sigc::signals as well, since
>   sigc::slot happily wraps them up now.
>
> It still doesn't work with classes that have an overloaded operator(), but you
>   can always use a lambda for those cases.

The code:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <sigc++/sigc++.h>

namespace sigc
{
  template <typename Functor>
  struct functor_trait<Functor, false>
  {
    typedef decltype (::sigc::mem_fun(std::declval<Functor&>(),
                                      &Functor::operator())) _intermediate;
    typedef typename _intermediate::result_type result_type;
    typedef Functor functor_type;
  };
}
```

It'd be great if someone could explain why this works, as I would like to learn the mechanics at play here.

Comment: _"It'd be great if someone could explain why this works"_ Shouldn't  this be part of your question, instead as a primary solution how to solve the problem?

Comment: The second template argument seems to correspond with the functor not being inherited from their functor base class. My guess is that they never bothered implementing that case, and from there, it's more straightforward to get the result type (turn `operator()` into a sigc-typed member function functor and use that to retrieve its result type).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, that would be a different question to the one I asked.

Comment: Well, that's just a detail of what and how you ask this question, if you're finally looking for an answer about how the found solution actually works.

Comment: @chris, the [follow up email](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/libsigc-list/2012-January/msg00001.html) suggests that you're right and this should be a patch to the library. Seems it hasn't made it in, or at least not at my distro's version.

Comment: It did make it into the library. See the mention of SIGC_FUNCTORS_DEDUCE_RESULT_TYPE_WITH_DECLTYPE here: https://developer.gnome.org/libsigc++/stable/group__slot.html#details

Comment: You probably want to use sigc::track_obj() too: https://developer.gnome.org/libsigc++/unstable/group__track__obj.html#details

Comment: The latest version of libsigc++ (2.5.*, which will become stable 2.6.*) requires C+11 and no longer needs the funky use of SIGC_FUNCTORS_DEDUCE_RESULT_TYPE_WITH_DECLTYPE .